# WP7 UI controls like button and listbox events are not fired, in a user control class

Tags: windows-phone-7, events, user-controls, uicontrol

I have a user control and in that user control there are ui controls like button and listbox, I have attached click and selection changed events of these controls from xaml and also tried by attaching them programmatically, but the events are not being fired.

any kind of help will be appreciated , 
Many thanks

here is the code .cs and xaml

```
            <UserControl 
x:Class="VisioLink.Views.MagazineListPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:views="clr-namespace:VisioLink.Views"
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit" 
FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"    
mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="768" d:DesignWidth="480"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True"
Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded"
 xmlns:local="clr-namespace:VisioLink.Views">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
    <Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="LightBlue"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                        <StackPanel x:Name="border" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <!--<CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{TemplateBinding IsSelected}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>-->
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Resources>

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <toolkit:GestureListener  Flick="GestureListener_Flick"   />
    </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="firstCol" Width="40"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="secondCol" Width="10"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <views:LeftMenuControl Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="leftMenuControl" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Row="1" ></views:LeftMenuControl>
    <Button x:Name="flipBtn" Click="flip_click"  Grid.Column="0" Height="70" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">

        <Button.Background>
            <ImageBrush ImageSource="file:///C:/VisioLink/Resources/Images/next.png" />
        </Button.Background>
    </Button>
    <Rectangle Fill="Black" Width="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Margin="0,0,0,0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Foreground="Black" Text="Nyhet" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>

    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="2" Margin="5,12,12,0">
        <ListBox x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="databoundListBoxMag"   SelectionChanged="listBox1_SelectionChanged" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" SelectionMode="Single">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border Margin="7"
                        BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="SteelBlue"
                        CornerRadius="3" x:Name="border1">
                        <StackPanel Width="450" x:Name="listItemPanel" Orientation="Vertical" Height="100" Margin="10,10,10,10">
                            <StackPanel x:Name="firstStack" Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image x:Name="magImage" Height="40" Width="40" Visibility="Collapsed" Source="Example4.PNG"></Image>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="itemone" FontWeight="Bold" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  FontSize="22" Text="{Binding name}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="itemtwo" TextAlignment="Left" Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"  FontSize="16" Text="{Binding content}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                            <!--<phone:WebBrowser Name="webBrowserContent"   ScriptNotify="wb1_ScriptNotify"  IsScriptEnabled="True"  Source="http://www.bing.com"  >

                            </phone:WebBrowser>-->
                        </StackPanel>

                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <!--<ListBoxItem  Style="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}">
                <StackPanel x:Name="itemPanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,0,28">
                    <TextBlock Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="nameBlock" Text="{Binding name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="379" />
                    <TextBlock Height="72" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  Name="detailBlock" Text="{Binding detail}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="379" />
                </StackPanel>
            </ListBoxItem>-->

        </ListBox>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
<!--Sample code showing usage of ApplicationBar-->
<!--<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="True">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button1.png" Text="Button 1"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Images/appbar_button2.png" Text="Button 2"/>
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 1"/>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="MenuItem 2"/>
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>-->
```

and here is its .cs

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Windows;
    using System.Windows.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Documents;
    using System.Windows.Input;
    using System.Windows.Media;
    using System.Windows.Media.Animation;
    using System.Windows.Navigation;
    using System.Windows.Shapes;
    using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
    using System.Windows.Data;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Xml;
    using System.Xml.Linq;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
    using System.Windows.Resources;
    using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
    using VisioLink.DTO;

   namespace VisioLink.Views
  {
public partial class MagazineListPage : UserControl
{
    public MagazineListPage()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }
    List<Article> articles = new List<Article>();

    public int CatalogId { get; set; }
    public string ContentToSee = string.Empty;
    private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        databoundListBoxMag.SelectionChanged += new SelectionChangedEventHandler(listBox1_SelectionChanged);

        // List<Magazine> listMag = new List<Magazine>();
        // listMag.Clear();
        if(IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Contains("magazineListPage"))
        {
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.TryGetValue("magazineListPage", out ContentToSee);
            DoProcessingOnData();
        }
        else
        {
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
            client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://device01.e-pages.dk/content/default4.php?customer=kaleva&catalog=" + CatalogId, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));

        }

    }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            ContentToSee = e.Result;
            IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings.Add("magazineListPage", e.Result);
            DoProcessingOnData();                   

    }


    private void DoProcessingOnData()
    {
        leftMenuControl.parent = this;

        leftMenuControl.contentToSee = ContentToSee != "" ? ContentToSee : "";

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(ContentToSee);
        XElement content = null;
        foreach (XElement element in doc.Descendants("article"))
        {
            XElement refId = element.Element("refid");
            XElement page = element.Element("page");

            XElement title = element.Element("title");
            XElement images = element.Element("images");
            XElement image = null;
            if (images != null)
            {
                foreach (XElement img in images.Descendants("image"))
                {
                    image = img.Element("medium");
                }
            }
            content = element.Element("content");
            String detail = Regex.Replace(content.Value, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
            String cont = "";
            if (detail.Length > 300)
            {
                cont = detail.Substring(0, 300) + ".....";

            }
            else
            {
                cont = detail;
            }
            Article art = new Article(title.Value, cont);
            art.detail = detail;
            art.page = Convert.ToInt32(page.Value);
            art.refId = refId.Value;
            if (image != null)
            {
                art.imageSrc = image.Value;
            }
            articles.Add(art);
        }

        this.databoundListBoxMag.ItemsSource = articles;
    }



    private void wb1_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        // The browser is zooming the text so we need to
        // reduce the pixel size by the zoom level... 
        // Which is about 0.50

    }



    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Article art = databoundListBoxMag.SelectedItem as Article;
        string id = art.refId;
        MagazinePage page = new MagazinePage();
        page._id = id;
        page._content = art.detail;
        page._title = art.name;
        this.Content = page;
    }
    private void GestureListener_Flick(object sender, FlickGestureEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Angle > 90 && e.Angle < 270)
        {
            // MessageBox.Show("right");
            GridLength len = new GridLength(50);
            firstCol.Width = len;
            flipBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            leftMenuControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        }
        else
        {

            // MessageBox.Show("left");
        }
    }

    private void flip_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GridLength len = new GridLength(200);
        firstCol.Width = len;
        flipBtn.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        leftMenuControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    private void SaveHTMLFile2()
    {
        string fileName = "TextFile2.htm";
        IsolatedStorageFile isolatedStorageFile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
        if (isolatedStorageFile.FileExists(fileName) == true)
        {
            isolatedStorageFile.DeleteFile(fileName);
        }
        StreamResourceInfo streamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(fileName, UriKind.Relative));
        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(streamResourceInfo.Stream))
        {
            byte[] data = binaryReader.ReadBytes((int)streamResourceInfo.Stream.Length);

            using (BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(isolatedStorageFile.CreateFile(fileName)))
            {
                bw.Write(data);
                bw.Close();
            }
        }
    }

}


public class BooleanToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToBoolean(value) ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return value.Equals(Visibility.Visible);
    }



}
```

}

Comment: show us the code that you tried(both xaml and cs)!!

Comment: Thanks but My question is that i have a user control that has a list box and button on it and the button has a click event and list has a selection changed event that are not being fired. 

Please help, many thanks

Comment: Did you try by placing break points inside the event handlers? How could you say the event handlers are not fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bubble click events through `UserControl`. See my answer on this topic: [Custom events in XAML on my UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067089/custom-events-in-xaml-on-my-usercontrol-on-windows-phone-7)

Comment: Thanks but My question is that i have a user control that has a list box and button on it and the button has a click event and list has a selection changed event that are not being fired. 

Please help, many thanks ,